# The convergence rate of Fourier series coefficient for analytic function

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, fourier-series

It is well known that if $f$ is a real analytic function, then its Fourier coefficients decay exponentially. That is, for a meromorphic $f$ say, if
$$f(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_n e^{inz},$$
then there are constants $K$ and $q$ such that
$$c_n=Kq^{n}(1+o(1)), \quad n\to\pm\infty.$$

In the following assume that, for some $r>0$, $f$ is analytic in $|z|<r$ and it has a singularity (a simple pole, for instance) at one point $z_{0}$ lying on the circle $|z|=r$.
I would like to know how exactly constants $K$ and $q$ can be deduced from $f$. I realize that it is related somehow with the singularity $z_0$ and corresponding residuum of $f$ at $z_0$. So far, I found only the Darboux's method theorem which is exactly what I need but for power series, not Fourier series.

Can somebody explain this? Is there some reformulation of the Darboux's method for Fourier series in literature? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Exponential decay does **not** mean that 
$$c_n=Kq^{n}(1+o(1)), \quad n\to\pm\infty.$$
It means $c_n=O(q^n)$ for some $q\in (0,1)$. There is no $K$ in general.

If a function is holomorphic on $|z|<r$ for some $r>1$, then its  Fourier coefficients on the unit circle are the same as its Taylor coefficients at $0$. The latter satisfy $c_n = O(q^{n})$ with $q=1/r$, and this is the smallest possible $q$ here. This is just a restatement of the fact that $$1/r = \limsup |c_n|^{1/n}$$